# Azure Key Vault - AADSTS70001: Application with identifier "xxx" was not found in the directory "xxx"

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am working on – Using azure key vault in web application. Implemented steps below, but getting error.

Steps:

1. Created azure active directory and added application in this directory. (copied - Client id and key)
2. Created azure key vault using power shell in the same subscription. (Successfully created key vault, along with some keys).
3. In web application code implemented using azure key vault library. But getting error saying that : -

> AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'c4687eec-d6f1-420a-8d25-9be20a78c98a' was not found in the directory a7682f3c-49a6-41f1-9865-343579044071
>
> Trace ID: b3653879-9603-4c10-a620-ded52f5c5d05
>
> Correlation ID: b740d27e-ab99-4f0a-9cec-9d57c4acc2d7
>
> Timestamp: 2015-11-19 06:36:32Z

This application exists in active directory in the same subscription.

Referred links:

1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/key-vault-use-from-web-application/
2. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/

Comment: I have a very similar problem. I have no idea what could go wrong. If you've found a solution, please post it

Comment: @t_tia try registering your application in the default Azure AD directory of your subscription. See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks @MvdD, I was not working on default directory. I tried in default directory and it's working fine now.

Comment: @t_tia try in default directory, if do not succeed comment here.

Comment: Only if there was a law to prosecute bad software designers.  After spending hours I still can't figure out what to do with this issue. My app IS inside default directory yet I keep getting the same message.

Comment: I am a paid subscriber to Azure services.  However, I do not have Office 365 subscription.  I use hotmail login to login to Azure Portal. Does it require a Office 365 subscription to add an application?  I am getting the same error as reported in this question.

Comment: @AllenKing, No it's not compulsory to have Office 365 subscription.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you've `Created azure active directory and added application in this directory`.

This means you've registered your application in the non-default directory for the subscription. Due to a limitation in Azure KeyVault, you can only authorize applications in the default directory to use KeyVault.

See this page for an [official source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903607.aspx). You can vote to have this issue fixed [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10510773-allow-key-vault-creation-in-non-default-directory).